# My Windows Service Application is not running when onStart (ODBC, C#, Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, odbc

I have just written a program to run as a Windows Service Application, GasMeterMonitoring; however when I start this application on my local machine, nothing happens at all.
 The Program is supposed to grab data from an MS Access database on another computer then insert that data into an Oracle database.
 I am unsure why this is not working. Any ideas as to what would cause this not to run properly? I have created a service very similar to this before that worked just fine. 
The difference that all the data was located on one machine, where in this code there are two separate machines. Also I am using timers with this code. To set up my I used the following [Microsoft Service Application walkthrough guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and an adaptation of the [timer code](http://clifgriffin.com/2008/11/20/using-timers-in-a-c-windows-service/).
I am just really asking for some help trying to figure this whole thing out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.IO;




namespace GasMeterMonitoring
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("GasMeterSourse"))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("GasMeterSourse", "MeterLog");
        eventLog1.Source = "GasMeterSourse";
        eventLog1.Log = "MeterLog";
    }        

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GasMeterMonitoring is reporting.");            
        timer1.Interval = 60000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GasMeterMonitoring is reporting again");
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GasMeterMonitoring reporting has been paused");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false; 
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GasMeterMonitoring reporting has stopped");

    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {           
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GasMeterMonitoring reporting has stopped due to computer shutdown");
    }

    public void EmailError(string ErrorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("ladante.riley@severstalna.com");
            message.Subject = "An error occured in GasMeterMonitoring.exe service";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ladante.riley@severstalna.com");
            message.Body = ErrorMessage;
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("DBN-EX03.severstalco.com");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(message);

        }
        finally 
        {
            // End-user will contact me otherwise
        }
    } 

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // ODBC connect strings 
            string connectionString = "Dsn=TakeCharge";
            string connString = "DSN=IDBS1;Uid=rouge;Pwd=steel";
            string sqlins = "";

            // Variables to be later placed inside the INSERT INTO query
            string dayTime = "";
            string hsmt = "";
            string boft = "";
            string eaft = "";
            string j9st = "";
            string lmbt = "";
            string fbst = "";
            string fcbt = "";
            string fdwpt = "";

            string fdept = "";
            string fdbt = "";
            string ffat = "";
            string ffpt = "";
            string fdnpt = "";
            string ftdt = "";
            string fppt = "";
            string fgpt = "";

            string hsmr = "";
            string bofr = "";
            string eafr = "";
            string j9sr = "";
            string lmbr = "";
            string fbsr = "";
            string fcbr = "";
            string fdwpr = "";

            string fdepr = "";
            string fdbr = "";
            string ffar = "";
            string ffpr = "";
            string fdnpr = "";
            string ftdr = "";
            string fppr = "";
            string fgpr = "";

            // Creates a MS Access ODBC and Oracle ODBC connection                             
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);
            OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
            DbConnection.Open();

            // Checks to see that the MS Access ODBC connection is open                
            if (DbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("MS ACCESS connection is " + DbConnection.State);
                DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Data.[Date / Time],DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Total],Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Total],Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Total],Data.[J-9 Shop Total],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Total],Data.[Ford Body Shop Total], Data.[Ford Chiller Building Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Total], Data.[Ford Final Assembly Total],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Total],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Total], Data.[Ford Paint Plant Total],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Total], DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Rate], Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate], Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Rate],Data.[J-9 Shop Rate],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Rate],Data.[Ford Body Shop Rate],Data.[Ford Chiller Building Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate],Data.[Ford Final Assembly Rate],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Rate],Data.[Ford Paint Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Rate]FROM DATA";

                // Accesses data from the MS Access ODBC connection then establishes a field counter to cycle through every column for every row
                OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
                OdbcCommand cmdnon = new OdbcCommand(sqlins, conn);
                conn.Open();

                // Checks to see that the Oracle ODBC connection is open
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("ORACLE connection is" + conn.State); 

                    // Create parameters for the Oracle ODBC connection
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(dayTime, OdbcType.DateTime);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(hsmt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(boft, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(eaft, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(j9st, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(lmbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fbst, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fcbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdwpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdept, OdbcType.Numeric);

                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffat, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdnpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ftdt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fppt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fgpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(hsmr, OdbcType.Numeric);

                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(bofr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(eafr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(j9sr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(lmbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fbsr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fcbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdwpr, OdbcType.Numeric);

                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdepr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffar, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffpr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdnpr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ftdr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fppr, OdbcType.Numeric);
                    cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fgpr, OdbcType.Numeric);

                    // Performs the insert query on the Oracle ODBC connection
                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        // Sets my variable equal to the values that are grabbed from the MS Access database table
                        dayTime = DbReader.GetString(0);
                        hsmt = DbReader["Hot Strip Mill Total"].ToString();
                        boft = DbReader["Basic Oxygen Furnace Total"].ToString();
                        eaft = DbReader["Electro-Arc Furnace Total"].ToString();
                        j9st = DbReader["J-9 Shop Total"].ToString();
                        lmbt = DbReader["Levy Maintence Building Total"].ToString();
                        fbst = DbReader["Ford Body Shop Total"].ToString();
                        fcbt = DbReader["Ford Chiller Building Total"].ToString();
                        fdwpt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn W Plant Total"].ToString();
                        fdept = DbReader["Ford Dearborn E Plant Total"].ToString();
                        fdbt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn Balcony Total"].ToString();
                        ffat = DbReader["Ford Final Assembly Total"].ToString();
                        ffpt = DbReader["Ford Frame Plant Total"].ToString();
                        fdnpt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn N Plant Total"].ToString();
                        ftdt = DbReader["Ford Tool and Die Total"].ToString();
                        fppt = DbReader["Ford Paint Plant Total"].ToString();
                        fgpt = DbReader["Ford Glass Plant Total"].ToString();
                        hsmr = DbReader["Hot Strip Mill Rate"].ToString();
                        bofr = DbReader["Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate"].ToString();
                        eafr = DbReader["Electro-Arc Furnace Rate"].ToString();
                        j9sr = DbReader["J-9 Shop Rate"].ToString();
                        lmbr = DbReader["Levy Maintence Building Rate"].ToString();
                        fbsr = DbReader["Ford Body Shop Rate"].ToString();
                        fcbr = DbReader["Ford Chiller Building Rate"].ToString();
                        fdwpr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        fdepr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        fdbr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate"].ToString();
                        ffar = DbReader["Ford Final Assembly Rate"].ToString();
                        ffpr = DbReader["Ford Frame Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        fdnpr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        ftdr = DbReader["Ford Tool and Die Rate"].ToString();
                        fppr = DbReader["Ford Paint Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        fgpr = DbReader["Ford Glass Plant Rate"].ToString();

                        cmdnon.CommandText = "insert into NAT_GAS_READINGS( HSM_TOTAL,BOF_TOTAL,EAF_TOTAL,J9_SHOP_TOTAL,LEVY_TOTAL,BODY_SHOP_TOTAL,CHILLER_BLDG_TOTAL,WPLANT_TOTAL,EPLANT_TOTAL,BALCONY_TOTAL,FINAL_ASSEMBLY_TOTAL,FRAME_PLANT_TOTAL,NPLANT_TOTAL,TOOL_DIE_TOTAL,PAINT_PLANT_TOTAL,GLASS_PLANT_TOTAL,HSM,BOF,EAF,J9_SHOP,LEVY,BODY_SHOP,CHILLER_BLDG,WPLANT,EPLANT,BALCONY,FINAL_ASSEMBLY,FRAME_PLANT,NPLANT,TOOL_DIE,PAINT_PLANT,GLASS_PLANT,DATETIME) values (to_number('" + hsmt + "'), to_number('" + boft + "'), to_number('" + eaft + "'), to_number('" + j9st + "'), to_number('" + lmbt + "'),to_number('" + fbst + "'),to_number('" + fcbt + "'), to_number('" + fdwpt + "'), to_number('" + fdept + "'), to_number('" + fdbt + "'), to_number('" + ffat + "'), to_number('" + ffpt + "'), to_number('" + fdnpt + "'), to_number('" + ftdt + "'), to_number('" + fppt + "'), to_number('" + fgpt + "'), to_number('" + hsmr + "'), to_number('" + bofr + "'), to_number('" + eafr + "'), to_number('" + j9sr + "'), to_number('" + lmbr + "'), to_number('" + fbsr + "'), to_number('" + fcbr + "'), to_number('" + fdwpr + "'), to_number('" + fdepr + "'), to_number('" + fdbr + "'), to_number('" + ffar + "'), to_number('" + ffpr + "'), to_number('" + fdnpr + "'), to_number('" + ftdr + "'), to_number('" + fppr + "'), to_number('" + fgpr + "'), to_date('" + dayTime + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS' ))";
                        int rowsAffected = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery();                           
                    }
                    //Closes the ODBC connections
                    conn.Close();
                    DbReader.Close();
                    DbCommand.Dispose();
                    DbConnection.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("ORACLE connection is "+ conn.State);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("MS ACCESS connection is " + DbConnection.State);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Sends an error to the event log, and email, the error to me regarding what is wrong.
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);               
            EmailError(ex.ToString() +"\n"+ "(" + ex.InnerException.ToString() + ")");                                
        }
        finally
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Gas Meter monitoring is functioning properly.");
        }        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have tested the connections to make sure that they are connected for hours and the chunk of code inside of timer1_Tick, they connect and can grab and insert data into the respective databases. I have looked at my event view but it does not say that anything is wrong with the service.

Comment: Are there any event log entries at all when you try to start it?

Comment: All of the event log entries work, except for anything regarding an error. I get the the onStart, OnStop, OnPause, OnContinue, but from the timer code chunk at all.

Comment: I don't see anything that does the `new Timer()` bit or wires up the event handler. Have you missed this or is it in the .designer.cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen when you declare Timer und the elapsed handler explicitly

```
private System.Timer timerX;

void timerX_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
timer1_Tick(); // alternativley copy the code from timer1_Tick...
}
```

and instanciate it in OnStart:

```
timerX = new System.Timers.Timer();
timerX.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
timerX.Interval = 60000;
timerX.Enabled = true;
```

calling `Start()` for timer is the same as setting `Enabled =true ;`

Comment: If I have this timer in the designer do I need to include anything other than timer.Enabled= True or timer.Enabled = False in their correct locations.

Comment: the time in the design won't work in a service... you need to a System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler is called `_tick` but from [looking on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) I can only see an Elapsed event. If this is the event you are handling then it looks like your EventArgs are wrong. If you look in the comments for the [timer article](http://clifgriffin.com/2008/11/20/using-timers-in-a-c-windows-service/) you referred to it says:

> I couldn't get this to work until I changed the event args in the
>   timer1_elapsed method to System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e

Perhaps that might be the cause?

Personally I have developed one Windows Service before and it is a tricky beast. I would recommend putting your code inside a class library and then calling it from there. Then you can write a console application and a windows service. You can run the console program to test out your code and you will be able to debug it and also you wont have stop / uninstall / install / start to test each revision.

When you are **sure** your code is doing what you expect you can then pop it in the service and install it. If you are handling any kind of file system access, stored cfg path, registry operation or other such permission based operation you can probably expect some further stumbling blocks before it works as expected :)

One last thing I would like to say before I part is you should consider if this really is a Windows Service or a scheduled task. If you need something to run at a regular interval and report information back then you should write a console app and add it as a scheduled task. If you need to build something that is always available and provides a service such as a server that needs to monitor for incoming connections or a drop folder watch that needs to know when something was uploaded then you should write a service.

Comment: Also, and I appreciate this is probably a half finished example you pasted, you should stop and resume the time in your `OnPause` / `OnResume` handlers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out to see if it works. Also, I do need it to run as a service. It will run on a server monitoring the data that has data being input every minute.

Comment: @Dante ok but that still sounds like a scheduled task that needs to be run every 1 minute to me :) maybe there is some of other code you haven't posted but it seems that your app collects the data from a database and something else is actually monitoring the gas meter + putting it in an access db for you to collect?

Comment: I guess that I did word that poorly but that is what the app does. It collects from one database and sends that data to separate database. 

Do you think that my added this following lines to service would fix this problem? If not, then I may take your advice and just try run the console app as a scheduled task.

timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick); 
timer1.Start() in the OnResume and timer1.stop() in the OnStop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Main method in your code?  Do you have one and just omit it from what you put in your question?

```
publci static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new Service1());
}
```

Comment: That exists in the a file called Progam.cs. If you see the first link that I have in my question, you will see that it is one of the first few steps taken.

Comment: The main method exists in a file called Program.cs, if you look at the first link that I list in my question then you will understand that I have done this already. Thanks though

Comment: @Dante - you need to have a Main method in your Service1 class as well as the Program class.  The Service needs to have an entry point, which is the Main method.  Did you do Step 5 under the Creating a Service section of the article in your link?

Comment: I followed step 5. 
"5. On the View menu, click Code to open the Code Editor. Edit the Main method to create an instance of MyNewService. When you renamed the service in step 3, the class name was not modified in the Main method. **In Visual C# applications, the Main method is located in the Program.cs file."**

Comment: @Dante - Got it.  I completely missed that last line when I was looking at it yesterday.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, don't worry about it.